# Regionale Verwendung des Wortes "arg"

Tags: word-usage, adjective, adverb, dialect, colloquial

Ich bin kein Muttersprachler des Deutschen und bin auf das Wort "arg" gestoßen. Laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/arg) ist es in jeder Bedeutung entweder veraltet oder landschaftlich, allerdings wird da nicht angegeben, in welchen Gebieten man es hauptsächlich benutzt. Im Gegenteil sagt [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/arg) nirgends, dass das Wort veraltet oder landschaftlich ist, außer dass er hinweist, dass es in manchen Bedeutungen umgangssprachlich ist. Mich interessiert, in welchen Regionen Deutschlands "arg" am meisten verwendet wird und, insbesondere, ob es für Norddeutsche (ich meine vor allem Niedersachsen) natürlich klingt. Ich würde mich sehr über eure Antworten freuen.

Comment: Die Verwendung in anderen Regionen kann ich nicht einschätzen - aber als Niedersachse kann ich sagen, dass das Wort als Synonym für 'sehr' in Verwendung ist und ich es auch nicht als ungewöhnlich empfinden würde (auch wenn es nicht sehr häufig (mehr?) verwendet wird). Ich würde mich arg wundern, wenn es als arg ungewöhnlich oder arg altertümlich kategorisiert würde ;)

Comment: @planetmaker Danke sehr!

Answer (score 4):

Du kannst *arg* als *sehr* mit negativer Wertung benutzen. Das ist zumindest in Norddeutschland ziemlich üblich.

> Der Wind hat sehr nachgelassen.

Ist das gut oder schlecht? Keine Ahnung!

> Der Wind hat arg nachgelassen.

Das ist schlecht! Flaute! Wir wollten doch segeln!

> <strike>Du hast dich arg verbessert.</strike>

Das passt nicht.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Und was ist mit der Bedeutung "schlimm, übel", z.B. in den Ausdrücken "arges Wetter", "nichts Arges in etw. sehen", "sein ärgster Feind" usw.? Ist sie auch noch lebendig?

Comment: As Adjektiv wie in *arges Wetter* ist *arg* nicht mehr sehr gebräuchlich. *Nichts Arges im Schilde führen* oder *sein ärgster Feind* sind hingegen feststehende Ausdrücke, die recht gebräuchlich sind.

Comment: Alles klar, danke schön für deine Erklärung!

Comment: @aldin: Im Schwäbischen ist die Konstruktion "etwas ist jemandem arg" noch gebräuchlich. Beispiele: ["es ist ihm arg, dass er seine Dienststelle und seine Kollegen in die Bredouille gebracht hat"](https://www.stuttgarter-zeitung.de/inhalt.stuttgarts-polizeipraesident-zur-pressefreiheits-debatte-die-aeusserung-des-beamten-war-ungluecklich.4c6949e0-7a7c-43b8-90a6-549c1eb68f08.html); ["Es ist ihm arg, dass er nicht mitsingen kann."](https://www.stuttgarter-zeitung.de/inhalt.der-maennergesangverein-harmonie-schwarzwaldmelodie.5a824ff4-2d9f-4a7c-886b-e33b9dd025a7.html)

Answer (score 3):

Zusätzlich zu Jankas Anwort: Hier in Baden-Württemberg ist der Gebrauch anstelle von "sehr" auch im positiven Sinn möglich, ein bisschen so wie "terribly" im Englischen.

> Das war schon arg schön. *([Pressebericht Reutlingen](https://www.welt.de/newsticker/dpa_nt/starline/kulturwelt/article112094521/Rentnerin-uebersetzt-Suetterlin-Texte.html))*
> Aber [es] geht uns arg GUT. *([Insider-Tipps Freiburg](https://www.lust-auf-gut.de/insidertipps-freiburg-klara-schmider/))*

Answer (score 1):

Zumindest hier in Wien wird das Wort als Synonym für "schrecklich, schlimm" verwendet, gerne in Verbindung mit dem typisch wienerischen "ur"; wenn man beispielsweise eine schlechte Nachricht in der Zeitung liest, kann man diese als "ur oag" (ur-arg) bezeichnen.

Answer (score 0):

Es wurde zwar explizit nach Gegenden Deutschlands gefragt, aber Deutsch wird auch außerhalb Deutschlands gesprochen (so wie Englisch auch außerhalb Englands gesprochen wird), daher erlaube ich mir auch einen Beitrag aus österreichischer Sicht zu liefern:

Das Wort *»arg«* wird hier gerne als Synonym für *anstößig* oder *krass* verwendet. Das kann vielleicht folgende Anekdote veranschaulichen:

In Österreich gibt es die Fernsehshow [Was gibt es Neues?](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Was_gibt_es_Neues%3F), die der deutschen Sendung [Genial daneben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genial_daneben) nachempfunden ist.<sup>1</sup> Vor wenigen Wochen waren Gurken das Sendungsthema, und als der Moderator [Oliver Bayer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Baier) der Kandidatin [Ulrike Beimpold](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulrike_Beimpold) einen kleinen gurkenförmigen Vibrator zuwarf, reagierte sie mit diesen Worten (aus dem Gedächtnis, daher vermutlich nicht exakt wortwörtlich):

> Ist das das Arge? Das ist aber jetzt nicht das Arge, oder? Oliver? Ist das das Arge? Wieso gibt du mir das Arge?

Hier wurde das Adjektiv zwar mehrfach in der substantivierten Form verwendet, aber dieses Beispiel zeigt trotzdem, dass das Wort *arg* in Österreich unter anderm als Synonym für *anstößig* verwendet wird.

Meiner persönlichen Wahrnehmung nach verwendet man in Deutschland in vielen Situationen eher das Wort *»krass«* wenn man in Österreich *»arg«* sagt.

Das Wort *arg* wird nur in sehr seltenen Ausnahmen im geschriebenen Deutsch verwendet, sondern fast ausschließlich im gesprochenen Deutsch, und auch dabei gibt es einen deutlichen Unterschied in der Häufigkeit zwischen Hochdeutsch (selten) und Dialekt (häufig).

In Wien und Umgebung<sup>2</sup> kann man häufig Dialoge wie diese hören:

> A: Host scho g'heat? Da Hofa is g'stuam. ("Hast du das schon gehört? Der Hofer ist gestorben.")
> B: Na **oag!** Was man scho an wos? ("Na arg! = Krass!" hier im Sinn von "Ach du meine Güte! Weis man schon woran?")

> A: Schau, wos is da mitbrocht hob: An Mercedesstean. (Guck mal, was ich dir mitgebracht habe: Einen Mercedesstern.)
> B: Bist **oag?** Du kaust do ned afoch so an Mercedesstern fladan! (Bist du verrückt? Du kannst doch nicht einfach so einen Mercedestern stehlen!)

Hingegen ist es in Österreich praktisch völlig unüblich, das Wort *arg* als Synonym für *sehr* zu verwenden. Die entsprechenden Beispiele, die in anderen Antworten vorgestellt wurden (*der Wind hat arg nachgelassen; das war arg schön*) wird man in Österreich allerhöchstens von deutschen Immigranten und Touristen hören, nicht aber von Österreichern.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*Genial daneben* wurde bereits zweimal eingestellt und nach mehrjähriger Pause dann von einem anderen Sender wieder neu aufgenommen, so dass bisher trotz Start im Jahr 2003 erst rund 400 Folgen ausgestrahlt wurden. *Was gibt es Neues* läuft hingegen durchgehend seit Oktober 2004 (mit Sommerpausen jedes Jahr), weswegen davon bisher schon rund 600 Folgen ausgestrahlt wurden.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>In der Metropolregion Wien (Wien + unmittelbar angrenzende Siedlungsräume) leben fast 3 Millionen Menschen. Österreich hat 9,1 Millionen Einwohner, daher lebt in diesem Ballungsraum fast jeder dritte Österreicher. Der in dieser Region gesprochenen Sprache liegen mittelbairische Dialekte zugrunde. Dieselbe Gruppe von Dialekten wird aber nicht nur in Wien und Umgebung gesprochen, sondern im gesamten dichtbesiedelten Osten Österreichs. Dort leben ca. 7,3 Millionen Menschen, also rund 80% aller Österreicher. Daher gilt vieles von dem, was für Wien gilt, auch für diese 80%. Lediglich in den dünner besiedelten alpinen Regionen im Westen und Süden herrschen südbairische Dialekte vor (1,3 Mio Menschen), die aber auch noch große Ähnlichkeit mit den mittelbairischen Dialekten haben. Ganz im Westen (in Vorarlberg; 0,4 Mio Einwohner) werden alemannische Dialekte gesprochen. Wie überall auf der Welt haben diese Dialekte Einfluss auf die konkrete regionale Ausprägung der Hochsprache.</sub>